# How to Convert a point Cloud to a Mesh

Tags: discussion

[image: Mesh to Point cloud]

This is a Duplicate [How can I convert a complex point cloud to mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301218/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-point-cloud-to-mesh) by  [Harry McKenzie](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/142292/harry-mckenzie)
This is a showcase of a Point Cloud turned into a Mesh.
This is not the Solution, which i'm not willing to provide 4 free after my experience here.
This is a reflection of how one does not get what he wants.

This is nothing but that or whatever u want it to be in your Head^^

I did try to engage in this community and since i did not obtain the Privilige to communicate (50 reputation LOL) i tried to communicate by Answering. Answering was not appreciated. Mods could actually turn my Answer to a comment & edit it to their likes, which equals dictating what i say. One can argue that i didn't follow the rules and that the system is in place to ensure quality. I'd argue if the rules & those in Power make it harder for Beginners to contribute at all, i'd rather not be an active Member of this "community", which imho (LuL) is more of a circle-jerk of those corrupted by power.

"High value Members" of this Community aka 24/7 reputation lurkers make it hard for beginners to answer Questions in order to get the reputation to communicate in a way they appreciate - which is commenting or Answering with a full & free solution to their problem -

I acknowledge that ppl here are actually helping others for free, but also like to point out that some do it as a necessity in order to achieve their goal of attaining powers over others by being granted with Mod-Tools or access to Databases of this platform.

I want to point out that cynical posting's of advice on how to use a spell-checker or how to conduct on the internet by User [Martynas Žiemys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60759/martynas-%C5%BDiemys) are a perfect showcase of the bigotry and a big.ego^^

I know you won't change due to this post and i'm not mad at anybody, but deeply hurt that my Pizza burned while i invested couple of hours to solve this & tried to engage **R.I.P Tonno e Cipolla q.q**

At this point in time nobody was able to answer original-OP's question and i got restricted from answering it or the reputation lvl was increased, idgaf^^ but next time some "noob" comes around just bare in mind that it doesn't need reputation to actually solve a problem^^

this acc will be deleted in a couple of hours anyways, so get out your downvotes, reports, advices & assumptions out asap, but be conscious about that i already closed this window. I solved the problem with no reputation in mind. I disengage

Comment: "This is not the Solution" Yes it isn't. Because it's a question. You can answer it if you want. Next,read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/1391712 You cannot comment without 50 rep. but you can answer right from the begining. Commenting does help if enough details aren't present in the quesn. You can ask for more details in that case. But if you dont have the priviledge of comenting, you can provide a few different variations in the answer. Next, "High Value Menbers". Yes there are some D-heads on this site. But if you really want to help others, just ignore them. And not all bad

Comment: Next, a question like this is more suited either for meta. Or Idk, maybe the chat. Although there are some people who simply want to answer for the reputation and therefore just cause trouble sometimes for other users, most people are completely normal. And if you do have an answer just post it. If you genuinely want to just help people, then just post the answer. Now, do make sure that your answer is of good quality and follows the guidelines of the site. Coz else, people will just flag it.

Comment: Personally I have never faced and kind of issue from the moderators. I can say, from my experience, that their actions are perfectly fine and that any mod on this site would do the same. In this case they marked the question as protected. This requires a minimum rep to answer the question. You can answer a few other questions and earn reputation from there and answer this question after that.

Comment: Hello and Welcome. For Questions about this site, the network, moderation, rules and how they work, please use [Meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: If you solved an issue to a question you have no reputation to answer, and really wish to share the solution with others you can always post a new question, formulate an inquiry framing the issue and answer it yourself below. Answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, even if it is a duplicate. If the answer is any good, you may even gain enough reputation to gain access to the original post, and answer it there. If you just wan't to boast, then I'm afraid this is neither the place nor the tone.

Comment: When someone posts a multi-paragraph diatribe against moderation with name callings and attempts of making it sound like it's funny, my first guess is that I'm reading a childish outburst at best. Checking the answers' history on the linked post just confirms it. But sure it's bigotry and big ego...